# Definition of diversity if Old World countries deemed not diverse enough

Tags: political-theory, terminology, diversity

One of the recent [answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83545/28396) I have seen the claim that

> the Western countries... see benefit in diversity.

What caught my eye is that it's really hard to argue that 1960s France (or Germany, or Spain) is not diverse. It is a large country spanning multiple climatic zones, with a range of different languages spoken, accents, regional cuisines, customs. It is one of the most culturally influencing countries in the world, and it does that in many distinct ways. I don't think you would mistake an urban Parisien with a fisherman from north shores, or that fisherman with another one from the Mediterranean coast. Throw in Brittany and Corsica and the country is already very multi-modal, this is before we even take population exchange with neighbouring countries into account, such as Spain and the UK.

So what is the definition of diversity of which all those people and cultures have unclaimed benefit, in light of subsequent mass migration from Maghreb countries and South East Asia?

Note that I can relate to how countries which are seen as bastions of conservatism in the EU, such as Hungary or Poland, may not be seen as diverse enough - they were remade after WW II as monoethnic and the influence of Communism dogma meant that social differencies had to be stamped out. But the same argumentation would not hold for Western Europe.

Comment: Where is the claim arguing that 1960s France was not diverse? I only the claim that it currently is diverse.

Comment: What's the benefit of diversity then, if they were already diverse?

Comment: What is the benefit of diversity in general? This isn't an absolute, proven fact.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the answer implied that benefit of diversity exists and that you need(ed) to invite more people to reap it. That has sparked my question.

Comment: related https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70790/21531